# Prevent keyboard from shrinking viewport

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, firefox-os

In Firefox OS 1.3, when the keyboard slides in, then the browser's/app's viewport height is reduced.

Simple test page/app illustrating the issue:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Test</title>
<div id="log"></div>
<input style="width: 100px" />
<script>
  setInterval(function () {
      document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = window.innerHeight;
  }, 100);
</script>
```

*Is there some way to configure a Firefox OS web app not to shrink viewport height when the keyboard slides in?*

Comment: I would guess that the change in vireport size is causing some kind of responsive reflowing of your content?  What about setting the body height to a set minimum? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/67VsW/) You could even set it via javascript after pageload so that it can be device specific.

Comment: @JRulle Setting body height doesn't affect viewport height. Furthermore, even if I could set viewport height to a fixed value on page-load, then this would be a bad idea: Naturally, viewport height should adjust when a device is rotated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are plans to facilitate this from manifest file in the future. It will be opt-in though. The implementation bug is here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=970093

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I also filed related bug [1038760](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1038760).